# Paging in uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am using a UITableview.In that there are nearly 100 records.I want to show 10 records at a time after that i will click on a button or UIPageControl which will show the next 10 records.So,please suggest me how can i do it?

Comment: Google it or search it here on stackoverflow. You will get your answer.

Comment: see this: http://www.lwxted.com/blog/2012/smart-data-loading-table-views/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanna create a table like that you could follow the below outlines.

In your button click Append or change the data in your data source array of your tableview. (Depending upon your requirement)

```
[self.myDataSourceArray addObjects:@"obj", @"obj2", nil];
```

Reload the table

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

**UPDATE FOR THE COMMENT:**

OK let me add some code,

//Consider this method is called when you click the next button

```
- (void)nextButtonAction
{
//Remove the older objects
[self.myDataSourceArray removeAllObjects];
//Add your new objects to the array
[self.myDataSourceArray addObjects:@"obj", @"obj2", nil];
//Reload the table
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i think this wud be fine for me..can u please give me the detailed code or explain me it properly..otherwise any helpful link for the above

Answer (score 0):

You could have a forward and backward button in the navigation bar with the page number

Answer (score 0):

Define a rect would you like to scroll and then call method scrollRectToVisible:newRect for UITableView

```
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableViewCell.height*10);
[tableView scrollRectToVisible:newRect animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is a good thing to introduce a pagination mechanism in your case. Because a `UITableView` should be fine for handling around 100 records. Just think of your Addressbook which can easily contain more than 100 records.

If you have a big number of records in a `UITableView` filtering and the index on the right with the letters of the Alphabet can help you to quickly navigate to the desired entry.

However, if you do decide to add more records to one table a common practize is to add a "Load more entries" cell at the very bottom of the table view.

For Example: Check out the Top50 Apps in the AppStore-App.

Answer (score 0):

This really goes against Apple's User Interface Guidelines.  TableViews are designed with built in highly efficient pagination (reusable cells).  I have TableViews with 4000 records and when the data model behind the TV is done right, it can be very responsive.

If you are dead set on this, you could use a button on the NavBar, Toolbar, etc and use that to call scrollToRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a count of the number of times the button is pressed

```
int i=0;

-(void)buttonPressed{
i=i+10;
[table reloadData];
}
```

then in

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath
{
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Arr objectAtIndex:i+indexPath.row]];
 }
```

Comment: ok...but my records are dynamic...i mean how will i get the next set of 10 records in my second page...how can achieve using the above method

Comment: i didn't get your quesiton ?, are you getting your records from a webservice , and do you get all the 100 records at d same time, if that is the case, then the above method works perfectly if you can store the records into an array and load the UITableview using it.